# Extracting certain fields from Splunk query results

Tags: splunk

I want to print the value of a certain field from a set of events that results from running a particular search query. Here's my query:

```
index=abc "all events that contain this string" sourcetype=prd
```

Now, this returns certain events that contain a field called `traceId`. What I want is to extract unique `traceId`s from the result and print them. Here's the query that I am using currently, but to no avail:

```
index=abc "all events that contain this string" sourcetype=prd | rex field=_raw "traceId: (?<traceId>.*)"
```

This query prints all the fields in the event (events are printed as JSON docs.).

Can someone help me with this? I have never worked with Splunk before, so please go easy if the question looks a bit easy.

Thanks!

Comment: It's nearly impossible to debug regex problems without seeing some sample events.  Perhaps, however, this is not a regex problem at all.  All fields are displayed because that is the default behavior unless you tell Splunk which fields to display (which you did not).  Try adding `| fields traceId` to your query.

Comment: @RichG Works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Answering this without some sample data is almost impossible... still, I think you are getting all data because:

1. you are not using the `fields` command to filter your fields of interest. It would go like so: `index=abc "all events that contain this string" sourcetype=prd | rex field=_raw "traceId: (?.*) | fields fiel1, field2, traceId"
2. your regular expression is greedy, which means `traceId` field will contain all text from that point to the end of the event. Try to be more specific i.e. `\d+` for numeric data or even `[^\s]+` for non-blanks.

~HTH